# Publishing ios app on App store?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, xcode7, uiwindow

If I resize the UIwindow to hide it will Apple reject my app?

Code:

```
self.window1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Thanks for patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it won't effect on your app in submission process

for more guidelines please read : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556

Comment: Thanks a lot ,I really appreciate your help.